# Java Generics Casting between Interfaces

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a question according to casting when generics in Java are used.
I tried to provide a small example that explains my problem.

IVariable.java

```
public interface IVariable {
}
```

IProblem.java

```
public interface IProblem<V extends IVariable> {
}
```

Algorithm.java

```
public class Algorithm<V extends IVariable, P extends IProblem<V>> {

    public void doSomething(P problem) {

        // ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from P to IProblem<IVariable>
        IProblem<IVariable> genericProblem = problem;

    }

}
```

Why do I need to cast the variable genericProblem explicitly to

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
IProblem<IVariable> genericProblem = (IProblem<IVariable>) problem;
```

and get a warning?

The method has P as an argument which is of type IProblem because V has to implement IVariable as well. 
Where is my mistake? What is the workaround?

I do not want to write

```
IProblem<V> genericProblem = problem;
```

because the input variable of the problem might be different.
Anyway in my opinion is `IProblem<V>` more specific than `IProblem<IVariable>`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

An `IProblem<V>` is not equivalent to an `IProblem<IVariable>`, even if `V` is constrainted to be an `IVariable`, because Java's generics are invariant.  Sure, `IProblem<V>` is the way to go, but if you don't want that, you can use an upper-bounded wildcard to express the relationship between `V` and `IVariable` instead:

```
IProblem<? extends IVariable> genericProblem = problem;
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic types needs to be an exact match. `V extends IVariable` and `IVariable` are not interchangeable types.  Let me give you another example.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(); // list of ints.
List<Number> nums = ints; // doesn't compile but this is what you are trying to do
nums.add(new BigDecimal(0.0)); // fine as BigDecimal is a Number.
```